# I am not getting the list item in my React-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I am new in React. I just created a React-app named TodoList. In my src/mycomponents, I have four files Header.js, Todos.js, TodoItem.js and Footer.js. I made some todolist and trying to show on display. But I am not getting any item. **I am not getting any error. The Only problem I am facing is that I am not getting any list item.**

**My `App.js`**

```
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./MyComponents/Header";
import {Todos} from "./MyComponents/Todos";
import Footer from "./MyComponents/Footer";
import {TodoItem} from "./MyComponents/TodoItem";

function App() {
  let todos = [
    {
      sno:1,
      title: "Go to the Market",
      desc: "You need to go to market to get this job done"

    },
    {
      sno:2,
      title: "Go to the Market",
      desc: "You need to go to market to get this job done"

    },
    {
      sno:3,
      title: "Go to the Market",
      desc: "You need to go to market to get this job done"

    }
  ]
  return (
    <>
      <Header title="My Todos List"/>
      <Todos todos={Todos}/>
      
      
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

'''

**My `Todos.js`**

```
import React from 'react'
import {TodoItem} from "../MyComponents/TodoItem";


export const  Todos = (props) =>{
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h3> Todos List</h3>
            <TodoItem todo={props.todos[0]}/>
        </div>
    ) 
}
```

**My `TodoItem.js`**

```
import React from 'react'

export const TodoItem = (todos) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h4>{todos.title}</h4>
            <p>{todos.desc}</p>

        </div>
    )
}
```

Tell me if code of any other file requires. I have attached the screenshot.
Thank you in advance.[image]

Comment: @PriyankKachhela I have changed, still not worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have couple of typing mistakes in your code.

1. You are passing capital Todos instead of `todos`

```
<Todos todos={todos}/>  // pass correct todos list here
```

2. In your `TodoItem` file you need to extract props correctly

```
import React from 'react'

export const TodoItem = ({todo}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h4>{todo.title}</h4>
            <p>{todo.desc}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Note: Since you are passing first todo item from `Todos` file, this will render only one todo item. If you want to render all todo list you need to change code like below:-

`Todos.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import {TodoItem} from "../MyComponents/TodoItem";


export const  Todos = ({todos}) =>{
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h3> Todos List</h3>
            <TodoItem todos={todos}/>
        </div>
    ) 
}
```

`TodoItem.js`

```
import React from 'react'

export const TodoItem = ({todos}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {todos.map(todo => (
              <h4>{todo.title}</h4>
              <p>{todo.desc}</p>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```